# How to json decode with exact decimal values in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json string something like

```
{
    "a":0.0000051,
    "b":0.0000051,
    "c":0.0000051,
    "d":0.0000051
}
```

when I try to decode it as `json_decode($json, true)` it convert all values to its exponent number as

```
array(4){
    ["a"]=> float(5.1E-6)
    ["b"]=> float(5.1E-6)
    ["c"]=> float(5.1E-6)
    ["d"]=> float(5.1E-6)
}
```

I want to convert json into array which has same value in decimal number without converting into exponent.

How do I do that?

Or Is there any other way to convert these number back to decimal number?

Comment: A quick & dirty approach would be to convert your numbers into string (in your json)

Comment: But How? I mean I'm getting this json string from a third party API response. How can I convert values into string in json?

Comment: Please describe why it is a problem. See, `0.0000051` and `5.1E-6` are exactly the same number for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @xs0, I need exact number for further calculation.

Comment: But `5.1E-6` **is** the exact number

Comment: @iainn, yes I agree, but I'm trying to calculate and send these number to payment gateway (according to my requirement) but it is not acceptable. That's why I need decimal number.

Comment: You can use `number_format` to format these back into "decimal" strings if you need to forward them on to another API/etc. If you're just doing calculations, leave them as floats.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari See: https://3v4l.org/Gggff, no issue..

Comment: I tried `number_format`, but it is returning zero, Can you please advice How can I use `number_format` and `sprintf`?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari see that example

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Yeah it's working.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Is there any way to find out the digit "7" from the number `5.1E-6`, as I said it is coming from third party API, and I'm not sure when it will change.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari I doubt it would change in lessening the precision, on the other hand if it was 10 not 7 it would still be the same number.

Answer (score 0):

first just store json data in a variable suppose `$json`
then try this

```
$result = preg_replace("/(\"\w+\":\s*?)(\d+\.?[^,\}]*\b)/imu",'$1"$2"',$json);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with PHP, which is a [loosely typed language](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php), you can store your floating point value as a string value in your json:

```
{
    "a": "0.0000051",
    "b": "0.0000051",
    "c": "0.0000051",
    "d": "0.0000051"
}
```

When reading your json you can use the snippet below to convert the string value into a float:

```
$a_float =  (float) $a;
```

Because you want to convert json into an array which has same value in decimal number without converting into exponent notation, I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
function float_to_string($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key] = float_to_string($value);
        }
        return $data;
    } else {
        if (is_float($data)) {
            $result = rtrim(number_format($data, 14), '0.');
            return $result === '' ? '0' : $result;
        } else {
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$json = '{
    "a":0.0000051,
    "b":0.00000051,
    "c":0.000000051,
    "d":0.0000000000051
}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = float_to_string($data);

print_r($data);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 0.0000051
    [b] => 0.00000051
    [c] => 0.000000051
    [d] => 0.0000000000051
)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/PLNfU